# EF Populate Navigation Property on Id match

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to populate a `List<Dock>` when `Profile.MatchId == Dock.MatchId` from different classes.

This is a stripped down version of both classes:

```
public class Profile
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ProfileId { get; set; }
  public int MatchId { get; set; }

  public virtual List<Dock> Docks { get; set; } = new List<Dock>();
}

public class Dock
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int DockId { get; set; }
  public int MatchId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the `List<Dock> Docks` navigation properties to correctly populate? I am believe I need to wire this up via `modelBuilder` - however have not done this before.

Comment: Since MatchId is no PK in either of these tables, the association you are requiring is no FK relationship and therefore not supported by EF. You'll have to do the "Join" in memory or set MatchId always equal to a PK value and then do the join over this column.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Ahhhh - that is disappointing.... I think I am just going to go with a linking table instead of this. Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score -1):

Good Time! There's a pretty simple example of model relationship configuration.

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dock> Docks { get; set; }

    protected override Void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Dock>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Profile)
            .WithMany(x => x.Docks)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProfileId);
    }
}




public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int MatchId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Dock> Docks { get; set; } = new List<Dock>();
}

public class Dock
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DockId { get; set; }
    public int MatchId { get; set; }

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - `Dock` doesn't have a `Profile`?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can't get values for List<> Docks in Profile, as you don't have direct connection between Profile and Docks.

You may try with this.

```
public class Profile
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ProfileId { get; set; }

  public virtual List<Dock> Docks { get; set; } = new List<Dock>();
}

public class Dock
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int DockId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Profile")]
  public int ProfileId { get; set; }
  public Profile Profile {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: pretty much everything is false there. There IS a direct connection between Profile and Docks, namely Profile.Docks. This would also populate this navigation property, if included, but on FK=PK (same as your solution, but with less clutter), OP asked for FK=FK.

Comment: I tried but didn't work.. can you give some exact answers